# IBM Speech to Text Alphanumeric String recognition?

Tags: speech-to-text, voice-recognition, ibm-watson, watson, ibm-voice-gateway

In trying to get Speech to Text (IBM Voice Gateway IVR app) to recognize alpha-numeric character strings, I am wondering if I could create a custom grammar or entity that would restrict STT to recognizing just individual letters and numbers, excluding words altogether. For example, here's a typical string: 20Y0H8C. Watson comes back with words and numbers, like "two" instead of "2". Digit strings work fine. I realize that letter recognition is problematic with typical ASR, but I'm hoping Watson is up to the task. I noticed there are no system entities for alphanumeric characters.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, set `smart_formatting` to `true`.

The smart_formatting parameter converts dates, times, series of digits and numbers, phone numbers, currency values, and Internet addresses into more conventional representations in the final transcript of a recognition request. The conversion makes the transcript more readable and enables better post-processing of the transcription results. You set the parameter to true to enable smart formatting, as in the following example; by default, the parameter is false and smart formatting is not performed.

**Check:**

```
curl -X POST -u {username}:{password}
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--data-binary @{path}audio-file.flac
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?smart_formatting=true"
```

**Result:**

*Voice*: The quantity is one million one hundred and one

*Result:* The quantity is 1000101

Check IBM Official [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/output.html#smart_formatting).

**Note**: The smart formatting feature is currently beta functionality that is available for US English only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the issue is when letters are spoken in the string. Smart_formatting is already enabled, but there's nothing for alphanumeric strings. I've also tried using input.text.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"), which works while using a chat window, but is hit or miss using STT.  The goal is to get watson to accept only alphanumeric strings, thus really constricting the scope. The data is fixed-length strings (7 chars) and the letters can be anywhere. For example: HV00310.

Comment: I should note that I'm using IBM Voice Gateway (STT is narrowband).